# Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:7.0.55.2 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)

Tags: maven, grails

He bajado mi proyecto desde git pero cuando lo compilo obtengo este error:

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: 
Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:7.0.55.2 from/to 
grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

Estoy utilizando grails 2.5.0 y JDK7, mi buildconfig:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55.2" // or ":tomcat:8.0.20"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"

    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0.2'
}
```

Creo que este repositorio está caído aunque he probado de añadir esta línea continúo con el mismo problema:

```
mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi proyecto tengo estos 4 repositorios y me funciona sin problemas.

```
mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```

¿Has pensado a migrar a Grails 3?

Comment: gracias ya lo soluciones, con respecto a grails 3 no se el coste de tiempo q podria llevarme

Comment: @sirdaiz podrías indicar cómo lo solucionaste? Gracias.

Comment: mavenRepo "https://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
  mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"